# Column header not visible in Jtable

Tags: java, jtable

using the following code, can't manage to get the column headers to show..Added Jscroolpane as well,but no luck...

```
String[] col = {"COLA","COLB","COLC"};
Object[][] data = {};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);


JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

contentPane.add(table);
table.setBounds(295, 11, 512, 411);
contentPane.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] col = { "COLA", "COLB", "COLC" };
  Object[][] data = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
  JTable table = new JTable(model);
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: How can I use this table in my current frame?Without showing a new frame? Tried contentPane.add(table); but didnt work...

Comment: Look at the containment hierarchy in my code: `frame --> content pane --> jscrollpane --> jtable`. So in your case, you would simply add the `JScrollPane` onto your content pane...

Answer (score 3):

When you construct the JScrollPane, you pass it the table, which is its only child component. But then you add the table to the contentPane, which means that you remove it from the JScrollPane and add it to the content pane. You must not add the table to the contentPane. Only the scrollPane, which itself contains the table.

Also, never use `setBounds()`. It makes no sense anyway since you're using a layout manager which takes care of positioning the components. And it makes even ess sense in this case since the table is handled by the JScrollPane.

Comment: I see, but if I remove the contentPane.add(table), I can not see the table at all...